# Example for the benefit from monotone convergence

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I want to see a (preferably simple) example where I can apply monotone convergence to a sequence of functions $f_n$ but where I cant exchange limitation and integration in terms of the Riemann integral.

Of course this sequence of functions should not be uniformly convergent but the convergence should be monotone.

Comment: Doesn't any example dealing with integration on a unbounded set, say $[0,\infty)$, work?

Comment: Can give me a specific example, please?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a function that is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Arkamis No, I found an example by myself in this case.

Comment: as long as the limit is still Riemann integrable, there is no need for Lebesgue integral. See Arzela theorem (both for dominated and monotone convergence), e.g. https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_13/dominated.pdf  The added value of Lebesgue is that the limit is always Lebesgue integrable - something which is not true for Riemann integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of the rationals and consider the sequence of functions defined $f_n(x) = \chi_{q_1, ..., q_n}(x)$.  Then $f_n(x) \to \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ monotonically so $\lim_n \int_E f_n = \int_E \lim_n f_n = \int_E \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ for any measurable set $E$.  Note that we cannot draw the same conclusion in the Riemann integrable sense because the functions involved are not even Riemann integrable.